# breadcrumb not showing over skew

Tags: html, css

i have made a skew div

this is the css for it

```
.bread_active{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 600;color: #3d4b2c;}
.bread_lst{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 400;color: #e0eed0;}
.breadcrumb{/*background-color: #85ba42 !important;*/padding-top: 15px !important;padding-bottom: 15px !important;margin: 0px !important;}
.breadcrumb>li+li:before {color: #e0eed0 !important;}
.filter_area{background: #edeff1;}
.bread_crmb{height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0 17px;
    position: relative;
}
.filter_area .bread_crmb::before {
    background: #85ba42;
    content: "dfds";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    width: 2000px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

and this is the html

```
<!--BREADCRUMB-->
    <div class="filter_area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                    <div class="bread_crmb">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="#" class="bread_lst">You are here: Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="bread_lst">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="active bread_active">Honda Accord - Diesel</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--BREADCRUMB ENDS-->
```

The problem is that breadcrumb list is not showing up
I have tried manipulating the z-index as well but it's not working
could someone help

Comment: can you upload a fiddle?

Comment: i am unable to upload it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove filter  `.filter_area{background: #edeff1;}`

and add z-index:-1 to 
`.filter_area .bread_crmb::before {`

Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xj9p1d0f/2/

Comment: I also want to add the background, is there any other way?